# How can I make that DIV-s arrange themselves automatically inside one main DIV, so there is no spaces between the smaller DIV-s

Tags: css, display

I am trying to make sort of block display, to display some sort of articles, I have one main DIV and 10 smaller DIV-s in it. I made that all the smaller DIV-s have 2 P thags inside of them. All the smaller DIV-s are autoresizable depending on the amount of the text in them. But I came to a problem where, when DIV-s are displayed, there is a lot of free space between them in the main DIV.

Thanks to the  "Rene van der Lende" he told me that this kind of layout is called "masonry layout".

Do anyone know how can I solve this issue.

**Here are some pictures and code that I used:**

```
**//This is the css for the main DIV**
.sve{
    position: absolute;
    width: 1320px;

    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

    top: 10%;
    left: 15%;
    padding: 10px;
    /* background-color: white; */
}

**//This is the css for the smaller DIV-s**
.sve .d1{
    position: relative;

    flex: 1;    
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: var(--boja2);
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 10px;

    height:fit-content;

    /* background-color: black; */
}


**//This is the css for stylizing the P thags**
.sve .d1 p{
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: var(--boja1);
    border-radius: 10px;

    /* background-color: var(--boja2); */
}

**//This is the css for the one of the P thangs which determines the width of the smaller DIV it is in
//Width depends on the amount of the text in this P thag**
.pN{
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    /* ⁡⁢⁣⁣ ⁡ */
    white-space: nowrap;
    
}

**//This is the code for the P thag that determines the height of the smaller DIV it is in
//Height depends on the amount of the text in this P thag**
.pT{
    margin-top: -30px;
    font-size: 20px;
    
}
```

**Here is the image of my Website, and how it looks like now** (https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DL9q.png)

[Here is the picture of the main DIV with the dev tools:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLasw.png)

I would like to make those free spaces disapear and to make all the smaller DIV-s be packed together.

I hope people will understand what I want to do.

**Here is the whole HTML and CSS code**

```
<!-- HTML  -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="theme.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="body.css">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

    <script>
   
    </script>
</head>
<body id="b">

    <!-- <p class="pNesto"> dASDBUAYfmdkadba duidfasgd asvdifascdi</p> -->

    <!-- <input type="text" class="nesto" id="nesto"> -->

    <div class="bg"></div>
    <img class="deco" src="pngwing.com (1).png">
    <img class="deco2" src="pngwing.com (1).png">
    <img class="latice" src="pngwing.com (2).png" id="latice">
    <img class="latice2" src="pngwing.com (2).png" id="latice2">
    <div class="header">
        <ul>

            <li class="">
                <img class="logo" src="—Pngtree—sakura flowers commercial elements_4082586.png" >
            </li>

            <li class="">
                <a href="theme.html" target="_blank" class=""> Pocetna</a>
            </li>
            
    
            <li class="">
                <a href="" class="k"> Kontak</a>
            </li>
    
            <li class="">
                <a href="" class=""> Vise informacija</a>
            </li>

            <li class="pet">
                <!-- <p class="pre">DASI</p> -->
                <input  type="text" class="pre" id="pre">
            </li>

            <li class="">
                <button class="preButton" id="preButton">Search</button>
            </li>
    
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="sve" id="sve">
    
        <div class="d1" id="d1">
            <p class="pN"   id="p1">Attack on Titan</p>
            <p class="pT" >Attack on Titan is a old popular anime. The author is
                Hajime Isayama. He is very famous Japanese manga author. ndhuvdutasu dut sautd tsa tdgas t t dfasoudou ouo u gusduysagdhojaso ygu </p>
        </div>
    
        <div class="d1" id="d1">
            <p class="pN"   id="p2">Tokyo Revengers</p>
            <p class="pT" >Prejak animee loooool</p>
        </div>
    
        <div class="d1" id="d1">
            <p class="pN"  id="p3">K - On</p>
            <p class="pT">Opek neki tekst o animeu</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="d1" id="d1">
            <p class="pN"   id="p4">The Miswit of Demon Kind Accademy</p>
            <p class="pT">Nesto o animeu</p>
        </div>
        
        
        <div class="d1" id="d1">
            <p class="pN"   id="p5">Demon Slayer</p>
            <p class="pT" > Tekst o animeu, kao nesto ne znam</p>
        </div>
        
        
        <div class="d1" id="d1">
            <p class="pN"   id="p6">Death Note</p>
            <p class="pT" > Isto prejak anime, ali su ga na kraju usrali</p>
        </div>
        
        
        <div class="d1" id="d1">
            <p class="pN"   id="p7">Horimiya</p>
            <p class="pT" > Prelep anime, savki prep</p>
        </div>
        
        
        <div class="d1" id="d1">
            <p class="pN"   id="p8">Future Diary</p>
            <p class="pT" > Mngo dobar anime, prep </p>
        </div>
        
        
        <div class="d1" id="d1">
            <p class="pN"   id="p9">Haikyuu</p>
            <p class="pT" > Obojkaaaaaaaa</p>
        </div>
        
        
        <div class="d1" id="d1">
            <p class="pN"   id="p10">Baki</p>
            <p class="pT" > Beautifuluu</p>
        </div>
        
    </div>



    <script src="theme.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
/* CSS */
*{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0.1px;
    border: 0px;
    outline: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    
}
.bg{
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, var(--gradient1) 10%, var(--gradient2) ) ;

    /* background-color: #4158D0;
    background-image: linear-gradient(43deg, #4158D0 0%, #C850C0 46%, #FFCC70 100%); */


    /* background: linear-gradient(45deg, black 10%, red ) ; */
    width: 1920px;
    height: 1080px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -90;
}


body{
    --boja1: rgb(20,8,42);
    --boja2: rgb(252,245,219);
    --boja3: rgb(197,161,176);


    --gradient1: rgb(212,149,143);

    --gradient2: rgb(189,156,173);
    
    
    /* background-color: #4158D0;
    background-image: linear-gradient(43deg, #4158D0 0%, #C850C0 46%, #FFCC70 100%); */

    /* background: linear-gradient(150deg, black 50%, red ) ; */
    /* margin: 2000px; */
    
    
    
    overflow-x: hidden;
    /* overflow-y: hidden; */
    opacity: 1;
}
.pNesto{
    /* width: 100px; */
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 20%;
    z-index: 1000000;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
}
.nesto{
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 20%;
    z-index: 100000;
    outline: 3px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}

.header{
    position: fixed;
    background-color: var(--boja1);
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99;
}
ul{
    display: flex;
    /* background-color: white;  */
    width: 800px;
    position: relative;
    left: 33%;
    
}
ul li{
    text-align: center;
    /* background-color: red; */
    margin-left: 30px;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 14px;
    
}
ul li a{
    color: var(--boja2);
    /* background-color: blue; */
    padding: 14px;
    padding-bottom: 14px;
    padding-top: 15px;
}
ul li a:hover{
    background-color: var(--boja2);
    color: var(--boja1);
}

.logo{
    position: relative;
    /* background-color: white; */
    margin-top: -14px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
.logo:hover{
    transform: rotateZ(180deg);
}
.deco{
    z-index: 5;
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: -30px;
    margin-left: -25px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 800px;
    transform: rotateZ(180deg);
    z-index: 100;
}
.deco2{
    z-index: 5;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0%;
    margin-top: -30px;
    margin-right: -25px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 800px;
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
    z-index:100;
}
.latice{
    position: absolute;
    /* background-color: white; */
    top: -150%;
    left: 30%;
    rotate: 90deg;
    width: 500px;
    height: 1800px;
    transition-duration: 8s;
    display: block;
    z-index: 1100;
}
.latice2{
    position: absolute;
    /* background-color: white; */
    top: -150%;
    left: 30%;
    rotate: 90deg;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
    width: 500px;
    height: 1800px;
    transition-duration: 8s ;
    transition-delay: 0.5s;
    display: block;
    z-index: 100;
}

.pre{
    position: absolute;
    height: 20px;
    outline: 2px solid var(--gradient1);
    background-color: var(--boja2);
    padding-left: 5px;
    color: var(--boja1);
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.pre:focus{
    background-color: var(--gradient1);
    outline: 2px solid var(--boja2);
    color: var(--boja2);
    /* text-shadow: 1px 1px 10px purple; */
    
}

.preButton{
    color: var(--boja1);
    margin-left: 170px;
    border: 2px solid;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: var(--boja2);
    padding: 5px; 
    margin-top: -5px;
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
    font-weight: bold;
    /* text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black; */
    /* border: none; */
    border: 2px solid var(--gradient1);
    border-radius: 10px;
    
}
.preButton:hover{
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
.preButton:active{
    transform: scale(0.99);
    background-color: var(--boja2);
    border: 2px solid var(--gradient1);
    color: var(--boja1);
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
    .sve .d1 {
        height:auto;
    }
    .sve .d1 {
        width:100%;
    }
}


.sve{
    position: absolute;
    width: 1320px;

    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;


    
    top: 10%;
    left: 15%;
    padding: 10px;
    /* background-color: white; */
}
.sve .d1{
    position: relative;

    flex: 1;    
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: var(--boja2);
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 10px;

    height:fit-content;

    align-self: stretch
    

    /* background-color: black; */
}
.sve .d1 p{
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: var(--boja1);
    border-radius: 10px;

    /* background-color: var(--boja2); */
}
.pN{
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    /* ⁡⁢⁣⁣ ⁡ */
    white-space: nowrap;
    
    
}
.pT{
    margin-top: -30px;
    font-size: 20px;
    
    
}
```

```
// AND HERE IS SOME UNFINISHED JAVASCRIPT THAT I AM WORKING ON
let x=document.getElementById("latice");
let x2=document.getElementById("latice2");
function load(){
    x.style.top="100%";
}
function load2(){
    x2.style.top="100%";

}

document.getElementById("b");
b.style.opacity="1";
document.onload=load();
document.onload=load2();
// console.log("Ble");
function brisi(){
    x.style.display="none";
    x2.style.display="none";
}

setTimeout(brisi,4500) ;


//⁡⁢⁣⁣ ⁡


let da;
let preButton=document.getElementById("preButton");


preButton.onclick=()=>{
    da=document.getElementById("pre").value;
    console.log(da);
}

let p1=document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML;
let p2=document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML;
let p3=document.getElementById("p3").innerHTML;
let p4=document.getElementById("p4").innerHTML;
let p5=document.getElementById("p5").innerHTML;
let p6=document.getElementById("p6").innerHTML;
let p7=document.getElementById("p7").innerHTML;
let p8=document.getElementById("p8").innerHTML;
let p9=document.getElementById("p9").innerHTML;
let p10=document.getElementById("p10").innerHTML;

let niz = [p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8,p9,p10];


for (const item of niz) {
    console.log(item);
}





// var _window = jQuery( window );
// jQuery(window).on('load', function () {
//      if(_window.innerWidth() > 767){ 
//      if(document.getElementById('sve') !== null) {  
//      var d1 = jQuery("sve").height();  console.log('total height: '+d1);
//      var d1half = parseInt(d1 * .60);/* Adjust this percentage to accommodate your situation best */
//      jQuery("sve").height(d1half); console.log('new height: '+d1half);
//          }
//  }
//  });
```

Comment: Check in your devtools what the free space consists of. My guess is padding.

Comment: What you are looking for is the "masonry layout". Flexbox does not provide this out of the box. You can try to use `align-self: stretch`  on flexbox child elements, but this will only fill the gaps, not rearrange the layout to fill the gaps like masonry would.

Comment: BTW, also post your HTML so people on SO have a running [reprex] they can toy with to help you with your issue...

Answer (score 0):

I found some althernatives to making this work.

```
/* I added this for the main DIV aka (.sve) */
display: column;
    columns: 3;
    gap: 1em;
```

```
/* And this for the smaller DIV-s aka (.sve .d1) */
margin-bottom: 1em;
```

It's not perfet but it is deacent.

If someone know's the better solution, feel free to leave it here.

[This is how the website looks after I added this changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdmQd.png)